# npm run serve failed vuexy

Tags: vue.js, templates, compiler-errors, admin

I have downloaded vuexy admin panel. Then in cmd i navigated to vuexy-full-version which is located in vue-version>vuexy-bootstrapvue, and after thhat i run command npm run serve and got this error

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 15 errors                                                                     12:07:27 PM

 error  in ./src/views/apps/e-commerce/e-commerce-product-details/ECommerceProductDetails.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\e-commerce\e-commerce-product-details\ECommerceProductDetails.vue
  188:1  error  Dependency cycle via @/router:1=>./routes/apps:7                       import/no-cycle
  197:1  error  Dependency cycle via @core/utils/utils:2=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 171:11-99
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/e-commerce/e-commerce-shop/ECommerceShop.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\e-commerce\e-commerce-shop\ECommerceShop.vue
  238:1  error  Dependency cycle via @core/utils/utils:2=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 122:11-78
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/e-commerce/e-commerce-wishlist/ECommerceWishlist.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\e-commerce\e-commerce-wishlist\ECommerceWishlist.vue
  95:1  error  Dependency cycle via @core/utils/utils:2=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 139:11-86
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/email/Email.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\email\Email.vue
  264:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle
  265:1  error  Dependency cycle via @/router:1=>./routes/apps:7             import/no-cycle

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 19:11-49 29:11-49 45:11-49
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/invoice/invoice-edit/InvoiceEdit.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\invoice\invoice-edit\InvoiceEdit.vue
  612:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 230:11-70
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/invoice/invoice-list/InvoiceList.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\invoice\invoice-list\InvoiceList.vue
  280:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 212:11-70
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/invoice/invoice-preview/InvoicePreview.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\invoice\invoice-preview\InvoicePreview.vue
  341:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 218:11-76
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/todo/Todo.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\todo\Todo.vue
  185:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle
  186:1  error  Dependency cycle via @/router:1=>./routes/apps:7             import/no-cycle

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 64:11-47 74:11-47 90:11-47
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/user/users-edit/UsersEdit.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\user\users-edit\UsersEdit.vue
  79:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 205:11-63
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/user/users-list/UsersList.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\user\users-list\UsersList.vue
  222:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7                        import/no-cycle
  224:1  error  Dependency cycle via @core/utils/filter:3=>./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 193:11-63
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/apps/user/users-view/UsersView.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\apps\user\users-view\UsersView.vue
  68:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./routes/apps:7  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/apps.js 199:11-63
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/card/card-statistic/CardStatistic.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\card\card-statistic\CardStatistic.vue
  253:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/ui-elements/index:9=>./cards:1  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/ui-elements/cards.js 38:11-66
 @ ./src/router/routes/ui-elements/index.js
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/dashboard/analytics/Analytics.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\dashboard\analytics\Analytics.vue
  70:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/dashboard:8  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/dashboard.js 8:11-62
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/pages/blog/BlogDetail.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\pages\blog\BlogDetail.vue
  367:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/pages:10  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/pages.js 286:11-54
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/views/pages/blog/BlogList.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vuexy-full-version\src\views\pages\blog\BlogList.vue
  225:1  error  Dependency cycle via ./utils:1=>@/router:1=>./routes/pages:10  import/no-cycle

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/router/routes/pages.js 269:11-52
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Looks like every error has something to do with eslint-loader.
Does anyone know what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I just solved my problem by deleting eslint-loader with command npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, then again npm run serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my problem by deleting `eslint-loader` with the command:

```
npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```

Then running:

```
npm run serve
```

It still runs on the server, but on the browser it gets stuck on the loading.

Answer (score 0):

dont delete it. its just cycle warning. reinstall it and add code to ./.eslintrc.js :

'import/no-cycle': 'off',

in rules array.
example:

```
rules: {
'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',

semi: ['error', 'never'],
'max-len': 'off',
'linebreak-style': 'off',
'import/no-cycle': 'off',
'prefer-template': 'off',
'no-alert': 'off',
camelcase: ['error', { properties: 'never', ignoreDestructuring: true, ignoreImports: true }],
'arrow-parens': ['error', 'as-needed'],
'vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline': 'off',
```

},